# JavaScript .floor number

Tags: javascript

I want to floor a number always in the same frame of 6 numbers

so if I would have i.e. a number between 7-13 I want to floor it to 6. If I would have number inbetween 14-20 I would like to floor it to 13, 21-27 to 20 etc etc. I there any possility to do this with `floor()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function weirdFloor(n) {
  return Math.floor(n / 7) * 7 - 1;
}
```